# Using Super in a Derived Class Constructor When Base Class Requires Exceptions to be Caught

Tags: java, exception, constructor, derived-class, super

I'm trying to derive a class B to a new class C in Java.  The base class constructor requires that unreported exceptions must be thrown or caught.  But if I try to put super(..) inside a try/catch then I'm told that the call to super must be the first statement in the constructor.  Does anyone know a way around this?

```
public class C extends B
{
   //Following attempt at a constructor generates the error "Undeclared exception E; must be caught or declared
   //to be thrown
    public C(String s)
    { 
         super(s);
    }

    //But the below also fails because "Call to super must be the first statement in constructor"
    public C(String s)
    {
         try
         {
              super(s);
         }
          catch( Exception e)
         {
         }
     }
 }
```

Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: `public C(String s) throws Exception` ?

Comment: Yep, your stuck with someone else's bad decision to throw a checked exception from a constructor. You will define your constructor with a checked exception as well.

Comment: If you think about it, what could you possibly do to recover from the exception?  When a constructor throws an exception, the object is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always **declare** the `Exception` in constructor signature using throws clause.

```
public C(String s) throws WhatEverException
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I am aware of is to throw the exception in the subclass constructor too.

```
public class B {
    public B(String s) throws E {
       // ... your code .../
    }
}

public class C extends B {
   public C(String s) throws E { 
       super(s);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't define constructor without calling super constructor in first statement. If it is possible You can throw runtime exception then You needn't to write try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are three things that you need to understand.

1. In a child constructor super must be the first statement,
2. If a parent class method throws exception then the child class has the option to either catch it or throw the exception back to parent class.
3. You cannot reduce the scope the exception in child class.

Example -

```
public class Parent {

public Parent(){
    throw new NullPointerException("I am throwing exception");
}

public void sayHifromParent(){
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
}


public class Child extends Parent{

public Child()throws NullPointerException{

    super();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child child = new Child();
    System.out.println("Hi");
    child.sayHifromParent();

}

}
```